# Can I delete a custom field and a custom object manually in the production org?

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, delete, production

I know that some options that are in the sandbox might not be in production.
I'll have to delete a Custom Field  and a Custom Object in production org. I need to know if it's possible to do manually or if I'll have to create a deploy package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this in PROD provided that the custom field(s)/object(s) are not referenced by anything that you can't change directly in PROD:

- Apex class
- Apex trigger

References in VF pages or other UX components will fail at runtime

If you are in the habit of doing changes in scratch org/sandboxes and then deploying to PROD, then you should stick to this best practice - especially if using version control as a source of truth.

Orgs that allow direct delete of schema elements in PROD run the risk of runtime failures or unexpected behavior